# Double rm verification in zsh

Tags: zsh, rm

When I do a rm * in zsh, I get something like this:

```
2014-06-08 10:14:23 $ rm *
zsh: sure you want to delete all the files in /home/assay/assay/log [yn]? y
rm: remove regular file `development.log'? y
```

First zsh asks me if I am sure I want to delete all, and then rm asks for for each specific file.

How can I just have the zsh verification?

Comment: Use `rm -f ./*`. By default, `rm` doesn't ask anything unless you don't have write permission to the file. Maybe you have a `alias rm='rm -i'`

Comment: Oh that must be it - I am running the deletes from within a Vagrant shell, and the files are hosted on the laptop file system. Thanks

Comment: Just a note, zsh still prompts on "rm -rf *", this can be disabled with `setopt rmstarsilent`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The message “zsh: sure you want to delete all the files” is a zsh feature, specifically triggered by invoking a command called `rm` with an argument that is `*` or `something/*` before glob expansion. You can turn this off with [`setopt rm_star_silent`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-RM_005fSTAR_005fSILENT).

The message “rm: remove regular file” comes from the `rm` command itself. It will not show up by default, it only appears when `rm` is invoked with the option `-i`. If you don't want this message, don't pass that option. Even without `-i`, `rm` prompts for confirmation (with a different message) if you try to delete a read-only file; you can remove this confirmation by passing the option `-f`.

Since you didn't pass `-i` on the command line, `rm` is presumably an alias for `rm -i` (it could also be a function, a non-standard wrapper command, or a different alias, but the alias `rm -i` is by far the most plausible). Some default configurations include `alias rm='rm -i'` in their shell initialization files; this could be something that your distribution or your system administrator set up, or something that you picked up from somewhere and added to your configuration file then forgot. Check your `~/.zshrc` for an alias definition for `rm`. If you find one, remove it. If you don't find one, add a command to remove the alias:

```
unalias rm
```

Comment: How can we turn off setotp_rm_start_silent? would `setopt localoptions rmstarsilent` do the job?

Answer (score 7):

The correct command to disable the double verification seems to be `setopt rm_star_silent`. To enable the double verification do `setopt no_rm_star_silent`.

For more detailed information look at the man page for zshoptions `man zshoptions`or http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions

Comment: or `unsetopt rm_star_silent`

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why but the following works for me - no questions asked

```
rm -f **
```

Or, if directories are involved:

```
rm -rf **
```

Comment: I would **not** recommend that. Because with the `globstarshort` option on, `**` changes from being the same as `*` to being the same as `**/*` and remove every non-hidden file recursively.

Comment: Why do you use `**`?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer `setopt rm_star_silent` didn't work for me.
I had to `setopt rm_starsilent` instead to get rid of the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using oh-my-zsh tthe common-aliases plugin includes the rm -i alias.

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/common-aliases/common-aliases.plugin.zsh

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/170311)

Comment: @jayhendren -- it's not a link to documentation, it's a link to something to install to fix the problem...