# Why is zsh ignoring my -f switch when removing files?

Tags: zsh, rm, macos

I just moved to [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) from [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) on my mac, i hope this is the right place to ask.

Works great, although I've noticed that if I run rm, for example

```
rm -rf my directory
```

I always get a prompt asking me to confirm. Why does it do this despite me having the `-f` switch?

Can I turn it off?

Comment: Is `rm` a function or alias? What does `type -a rm` output? Are you actually doing `rm -rf my_dir/*` without setting the `RM_STAR_SILENT` shell option?

Comment: It says "rm is /bin/rm". i don't even know what the star_silent is... :) I have used rm since forever in all sorts of systems, and -f (force) has always had the effect of not nagging me, but now in Catalina it does so regardless

Comment: This is likely https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/135084/5132 again.