# Delete multiple files using rm with only one confirmation for everything (rm -i)?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, zsh, rm

I have an alias `rm='rm -irv'` and I want to delete a bunch of files and/or directories but I only want 1 confirmation message like `rm: descend into directory 'myfolder'?`

I don't mind confirming for each directory but not for each file within each directory. The zsh feature for `rm *` or `rm something/*` works well but sometimes I am just deleting files `rm *.txt` or a single file `rm document.txt` but I would still like at least 1 confirmation.

[This solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/135084/double-rm-verification-in-zsh)  comes very close to what I'm looking for but does not work in every scenario. So let's say the directory "myfolder" contains 100 files then I would like something that looks like this:

```bsh
~ > ls -F
myfolder/    empty.txt    file.txt    main.c

~ > rm *
zsh: sure you want to delete all 4 files in /home/user [yn]? n

~ > rm myfolder
rm: descend into directory 'myfolder'? y
removed 'file1.txt'
removed 'file2.txt'
...
removed 'file100.txt'
removed directory 'myfolder'

~ > rm main.c
rm: remove regular file 'main.c'? y
removed 'main.c'

~> rm *.txt
rm: remove all '*.txt' files? y
removed 'empty.txt'
removed 'file.txt'
```

Comment: That's a lot to ask for. How about you writing the code for that yourself first and then come ask about the parts that you can't figure out for yourself?

Comment: @MarlonRichert I was hoping it wouldn't need a hefty script but instead a command that works in a similar way to `rm` which allows for one confirmation before deletion. I've searched but no luck 'cause most solutions are closer to `rm -rf` using the `find` command. At the moment all I've got is `rm -irv` and that's the closest to my desired behaviour and I wouldn't know how to even check for different input arguments like comparing a single file, multiple files, a dir, multiple dirs or a wildcard within a file/dir name. So maybe there are already zsh specific ways to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: What makes it complicated is that you want to treat wildcards, directories, files and wildcards with filename extensions in different ways. That adds a significant amount of complexity. A bit too much for one question.

Comment: @MarlonRichert Which is exactly why I was hoping it was supported natively by some command other than `rm`. A single confirmation for any deletion - that is all I'm looking for. How would you suppose I go about solving this in multiple questions?

Comment: @MarlonRichert I mean, where do I begin? How would you start to try and solve this?

Comment: I added an answer that will get you very close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the exact prompting and output listed in your question is practically impossible (or an insane amount of work), but the following should have you covered for all practical purposes:

```bsh
# Disable the default prompt that says
# 'zsh: sure you want to delete all 4 files in /home/user [yn]?'
setopt rmstarsilent

# For portability, use the `zf_rm` builtin instead of any external `rm` command.
zmodload -Fa zsh/files b:zf_rm

rm() {
  # For portability, reset all options (in this function only).
  emulate -L zsh

  # Divide the files into dirs and other files.
  # $^ treats the array as a brace expansion.
  # (N) eliminates non-existing matches.
  # (-/) matches dirs, incl. symlinks pointing to dirs.
  # (-^/) matches everything else.
  # (T) appends file type markers to the file names.
  local -a dirs=( $^@(TN-/) ) files=( $^@(TN-^/) )

  # Tell the user how many dirs and files would be deleted.
  print "Sure you want to delete these $#dirs dirs and $#files files in $PWD?"

  # List the files in columns à la `ls`, dirs first.
  print -c - $dirs $files

  # Prompt the user to confirm.
  # If `y`, delete the files.
  #   -f skips any confirmation.
  #   -r recurses into directories.
  #   -s makes sure we don't accidentally the whole thing.
  # If this succeeds, print a confirmation.
  read -q "?[yn] " &&
      zf_rm -frs - $@ && 
      print -l '' "$#dirs dirs and $#files files deleted from $PWD."
}
```

For more info on `zf_rm`, see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002ffiles-Module

More info on glob qualifiers `(TN-^/)` can be found here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers

Comment: Oh wow, that's incredible! It does exactly what I want, works better than I expected and I like the way it lists the files in columns and rows before confirmation instead of rows only after confirmation like default `rm -v` behaviour. How do I delete dirs only? `rm */` does select folders but it shows up as files in the confirmation message and does not get removed after pressing y. It's printed as `folder//` so I'm assuming the `zf_rm` tries to delete `folder//` instead of `folder/`.

Comment: @ntruter42 Like it says in the code comments, `(-/)` matches dirs only. So, just do `rm *(-/)`.

Comment: More info here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers